# cannot access scope's property in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass data to my directive's link function. When I console.log the isolate scope I see all the properties I want (`scope.x`, `scope.y` and `scope.categories`) and their values are strings. For some reason though I cannot access the categories property of the scope in my directive.

`{{ categories }}` is defined in the controller as an array of objects

**main.html:**

```
<div bar-chart 
        bar-data='categories' 
        bar-x='violation_category' 
        bar-y='["number_violations"]'></div>
```

**barchart.js:**

```
app.directive('barChart', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            x: '@barX',
            y: '@barY',
            barData: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            console.log(scope)  // shows an object that has barData array
            console.log(scope.barData)  // undefined
            console.log(scope.x)  // string
            console.log(scope.y)  // string

        }
    }
})
```

In the controller $scope.categories is populated like so:

```
Violation.categories().then(function(res){
    $scope.categories = res.data
})
```

Where the `Violation` service acts like this:

```
categories: function(){
  return $http.get('/api/violations/categories')

}
```

Comment: You will not be able to access the real objects in `categories` this way; use the `"="` scope binding (and remove the `{{...}}` from the attribute).

Comment: ok thank you. I now get undefined when trying to access (see update)

Comment: It is expected to be undefined, if the service hasn't returned yet... When the `link()` is executed it is quite possible that the service hasn't returned and `scope.categories` is naturally undefined. What happens in the scope when the service does return? (you may find [this firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/) useful)

Comment: understood. Had to `$watch` the scope for changes. `scope.$watch('barData', function(){ // do stuff })`